# How to use Query If Else Condition on Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql-server, azure, if-statement, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

So I have a query to compare the data, I want to compare between two table using `If Else Condition` on Azure Data Factory.

So here are dummy example T-SQL for the condition

```
BEGIN
SET @sales_detail_row = (select count(*)
from schema_A.SALES_DETAIL
where transaction between '2021-04-01' and '2021-05-16')
 
SET @pf_sales_detail_row = (select count(*)
from schema_B.SALES_DETAIL
where transaction between '2021-04-01' and '2021-05-16');
 
if (@sales_detail_row=@pf_sales_detail_row)
then print 'SUCCESS'
else
'FAILED'
END
```

How to implement these query into `If Else Condition` on Azure Data Factory ?

From this [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity), I don't really understand, because no explanation about the query method.

Comment: Hi @Rudy Tri Saputra Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can declare two variables `sales_detail_row` and `pf_sales_detail_row` in ADF:

   [image]
2. Use two lookup activities to exec SQL query.

   ```
    select count(*) as row_count from [dbo].[emp]
   ```

   [image]
3. Use Set variable activity to assign value to variables. Add dynamic content `@String(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.row_count)`.

   [image]
4. In If condition, we can use expression

   ```
    @equals(variables('sales_detail_row'),variables('pf_sales_detail_row'))
   ```

   to compare whether two values are equal.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much Joseph, now I realized that `If condition` on Azure Data Factory doesn't support with T-SQL Script, I need to convert the query logic into `ADF Dynamic Content`. So I want to ask, where can I learn this `dynamic content` on Azure Data Factory beside Azure Documentation on Microsoft ?

Comment: This [blog](https://www.bluegranite.com/blog/using-azure-data-factory-v2-activities-dynamic-content-to-direct-your-files) post is pretty detailed. If you have any questions during use, please come to the SO.